# convert string to object js function

Tags: javascript, string, javascript-objects

I've been trying to answer the following question but have no idea what step comes next. I've tried looking it up but haven't had any luck because most of the answers are in json and I don't know that coding language yet. Below is the question and the code I have so far. Thank you.

> Create a function named convertStrToObj() that accepts three string parameters. All three should be optional parameters. If a parameter does not exist set it to 'N/A'. Your function should return an object with three properties first, second, and third. Each of the string parameters should be assigned to that object's properties.

```
var object = {
  first: '',
  second: '',
  third: ''
};


function convertStringToObject(string1, string2, string3){
   // do something
}
```

How do I convert a string into an object using vanilla js?

Am I supposed to use booleans?

Is the object variable redundant?

Comment: the assignment doesn't want you to convert a string to an object. It wants you to create a function that returns an object with the string parameters assigned to it as properties.

Comment: I did not quite understand what you want, but is this what you want? - https://jsfiddle.net/tdf0wab9/5/

Comment: @dgeare Thank you for the edit suggestion and quick response. Ah, that sort of makes sense. I'll do some different google searches and see what comes up. Thanks again.

Comment: @TiagoMartinho Bingo. That is what I was looking for. Thank you. I'm a beginner so it difficult for me to know which methods are best for certain tasks. I wouldn't have known to use `object.first`.

Comment: Do you want me to post the answer, or is it not necessary?

Comment: @TiagoMartinho Thank you but I'd like to take a stab at it myself. Your comment was a big help though.

Answer (score 1):

Create an object and assign, checking each parameter.

Your question mentions 'does not exist'.  This is unclear as what to do if it is the `NULL` value.

This example does not enforce that the inputs are strings.

```js
function convertStrToObj(a, b, c) {
  const ret = {
    first: a === undefined || a === null ? 'N/A' : a,
    second: b === undefined || a === null ? 'N/A' : b,
    third: c === undefined || a === null ? 'N/A' : c,
  }
  return ret;
}

console.log(convertStrToObj('foo', 'bar', undefined))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function convertStringToObject(string1, string2, string3) {
  return {
    first: string1 ? string1: 'N/A',
    second: string2 ? string2: 'N/A',
    third: string3 ? string3: 'N/A'
  }
}

let result = convertStringToObject('a', null, 'c');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: From @terrylennox